# Django: user login not working

Tags: python, django, authentication

This is my login view:

```
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {})

def user_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details.")

    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

Now, when I enter correct login info, it redirects me properly, to /dashboard, but I'm still not logged in. What am I missing?

Comment: a call to login! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to issue explicit call to `login`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

It takes a `request` object and a `user` object.

Comment: Indeed. I still don't understand how I missed that :/

Comment: after I putting request beside user args, it still not work.